# Telerik Appbuilder Temp .JS files cleanup

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, temp, telerik-appbuilder

I am loading templates dymanically. i.e.,

`base.html`

`onLoad(loadSubPage1, 'some_div')`

- loads `subPage1.html` into `some_div` on the `base.html` page

  ** Note: the `onLoad` method loads the html.  The `.html` file has a reference to its `.js` file (so it's loaded dynamically each time I render the html).

  ** Note: to render the html I load it via ajax

This is my model on how I handle my app.  I am using `Visual Studio 2015` as my IDE.  For some reason I clicked on "Show all files (so I could see a hidden file)" I noticed a heap of `.tmp` files (see pic below)

[image]

The files you see run on mobile devices and not on the web.  How do I handle this?  I assume theses files (when running on the device) can pile up like this too.  What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://forums.asp.net/p/2092528/6044056.aspx?Re%20TMP%20files%20all%20over%20the%20place%20in%20VS%202015) you can go to **Tools > Options > Environment > AutoRecover** and uncheck **Save AutoRecovery information** option.